# MacOS Ventura: How to permanently disable pftctl

Tags: macos, firewall, pfctl

I'm on MacOS Ventura on M1 Apple Silicon. Something keeps re-enabling `pfctl` that blocks my internet access roughly every 10 minutes. I'm no expert in macos or `pfctl` but after a bit of googling, I tried deleting all anchor files I could find to no avail.

To counter, I have a small loop running that keeps disabling the pfctl every 10 seconds. But even then when it gets re-enabled it momentarily blocks all communication.

Does anyone know how to figure out what's triggering this?
How do I permanently kill pfctl so it doesn't start again?

PS: This is my laptop that I used as a BYOD at my workplace. After I switched jobs, I got IT to remove all their crap but maybe something got left behind?

Comment: Seems easiest to just wipe the laptop.

Comment: You either have to delete everything on the data volume, and then restore only documents from a backup, or else figure out what is causing the problem. If you choose the latter option, I suggest you start by looking in /Library/LaunchDaemons for anything you didn't put there.

Comment: I want to keep wipe all as the last resort. Is there a way to check what rules or anchors are being applied, and where are they on the hard disk?

Maybe we can delete the file, or alter the rules?

Comment: Start with /etc/pf.conf and check everything it refers to, recursively.